# How to add milliseconds to the time duration since epoch?

Tags: c++, time, c++-chrono

Using only the `std::chrono` library, I have a variable with type `unsigned long`, representing the number of milliseconds from 1 Jan 1970 to now, and I want to add 100 milliseconds to it.

```
unsigned long now = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
unsigned long t100ms = std::chrono::milliseconds(100).count();
unsigned long time = now + t100ms;
```

When printing `t100ms`, I get "`1000`".

If I print the value of `std::chrono::system_clock::now` every **second**, I see that the incrementing number is *not* increased with 1000 at each iteration (as 1 second is equal to 1000 milliseconds, this should be the case).

### Question

Does `std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()` not return the amount of time that has passed since 1 Jan 1970 represented in milliseconds?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()` is the *elapsed time* since epoch, expressed in whatever units the system clock chooses to use; these could be **attoseconds, or years, or anything in between**.  Clearly, adding a number of milliseconds to a number of nanoseconds (for example) is nonsensical.

If you want to perform arithmetic on duration values, you should remain in the duration types as they will perform unit conversion for you, and only call `count()` when you want to print out the result:

```
auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch();
auto t100ms = std::chrono::milliseconds(100);
auto time = now + t100ms;
std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(time).count();
```

Comment: `count` is a method, not a property.

Comment: Caution : if you do `now += t100ms` it does not work as expected, you have to affect the result to another variable and use it afterward (here the `time` variable).

Answer (score 2):

`count()` member function of the `duration` class returns representation in **periods**, which is internal.
It's not necessary will be seconds or milliseconds, it's just an internal representation. You can set the period manually for `duration` class, returned by `time_since_epoch()` function.

```
std::chrono::milliseconds foo = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch();
```

Now you have period value of the `duration` class is milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

### Beginning of time

`std::chrono::time_point::time_since_epoch` does *not* neccessarily return the time from 1 Jan 1970, instead the clock's **epoch** is implementation defined. Epoch is only meant to represent a fixed point in time that stays the same within an application session.

*E.g.*, on my system `std::chrono::time_point::time_since_epoch` returns the time since latest system start.

### Units

The date and time utilities in the `std::chrono` library are designed to work with *unitless* time amounts. This is to, *e.g.*, enable adding two durations with different units as hours and nanoseconds. The unit conversions are performed automatically.

If you want to express time amounts with a specific unit, use `std::chrono::duration_cast`. Also to get the time-amount representation as a number use `std::chrono::duration::count`.

```
using namespace std::literals; // To enable duration literals as, e.g., 100ms.
auto time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch() + 100ms;
std::cout << "Ms: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<decltype(1ms)>(time).count();
```